# iTextSharp and datagridview page break

Tags: c#, itext

I'm trying to export a datagrid to PDF with iTextSharp and need to make a page break when one column changes. I have this code

```
using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(savefiledialoge.FileName, FileMode.Create))
{
    try
    {
        pdfdoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfdoc, stream);
        pdfdoc.SetPageSize(PageSize.A4.Rotate()); // horizontal
        pdfdoc.Open();
        Encabezado();
        for (int i = 0; i <= dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Warehouse"].Value.ToString() == dataGridView1.Rows[i + 1].Cells["Warehouse"].Value.ToString())
                {                                     
                    pdftable.AddCell(new Phrase(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString(), text));
                }
                else
                {
                    pdftable.AddCell(new Phrase(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString(), text));
                    pdfdoc.Add(pdftable);                                                                                
                    pdfdoc.NewPage();
                    pdftable.DeleteBodyRows();                                        
                }                                    
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "error occured ", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

but I have two problems, one of the rows is added in a new page

[image]

and the compilation gives me an error:

```
"Index was out of range, must be nonnegative and less than the size of the collection."
```

Comment: Are you sure `(int i = 0; i <= dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)` shouldn't be `(int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)`? Also, the error you have doesn't strike me as a compilation error; it looks more like a runtime error. Finally, you have two unrelated questions in one post. The "index was out of range" error is one question; the keeping the rows together issue is another question (and the answer will be: upgrade to iText 7 if you want help).

Comment: @PhilippMaurer Only a partial duplicate, the out-of-range problem is merely a small part of the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the case differentiation inside your loop over the columns:

```
for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
{
    if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Warehouse"].Value.ToString() == dataGridView1.Rows[i + 1].Cells["Warehouse"].Value.ToString())
    {
        pdftable.AddCell(new Phrase(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString(), text));
    }
    else
    {
        pdftable.AddCell(new Phrase(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString(), text));
        pdfdoc.Add(pdftable);
        pdfdoc.NewPage();
        pdftable.DeleteBodyRows();
    }
}
```

The effect: Let's assume `i` currently is the value for the last row for a given warehouse. Thus, inside the `j` loop above you'll go into the `else` branch all the time, so

- For `j == 0` your code already adds the table with the still incomplete row `i` ("incomplete" as only the cell for the first column has been added) to the document. iText does *not* draw the incomplete row `i` but goes to the next page with that single column still in the table object.
- For the next values of `j` before the final column, the row still is incomplete, so `pdfdoc.Add(pdftable)` adds nothing to the page but stores the new cells in the table object. `pdfdoc.NewPage()` does not create yet another page as the current page still is empty.
- For the last value of `j` the row `i` finally is complete, so `pdfdoc.Add(pdftable)` adds a single-row table and `pdfdoc.NewPage()` creates yet another new page.

You should instead first add the complete current row `i` to the table in the body of your loop over `i` and only thereafter test whether a change of warehouse will occur in the next row; i.e. replace the quoted code above by

```
for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
{
    pdftable.AddCell(new Phrase(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString(), text));
}

if (i == dataGridView1.RowCount - 1)
{
    pdfdoc.Add(pdftable);
}
else if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Warehouse"].Value.ToString() != dataGridView1.Rows[i + 1].Cells["Warehouse"].Value.ToString())
{
    pdfdoc.Add(pdftable);
    pdfdoc.NewPage();
    pdftable.DeleteBodyRows();
}
```

Concerning the "Index out of range":

- On one hand don't compare the warehouse with the value in the next row if you are in the last row already, see above.
- On the other hand, as @Bruno already mentioned, the loop over `i` should stop earlier, instead of

  ```
  for (int i = 0; i <= dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)
  ```

  use

  ```
  for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)
  ```